# View in Browser Package for Sublime Text 3 wont let me open from files that are more than two levels deep

Tags: directory, sublimetext3, package

I installed view in browser package for sublime text 3 and Im having issues opening html files that are more than two levels past the home folder.

For example I have a developer folder saved in my home folder on os x and I saved an html file in Home>Developer>Html Class>Ch 2. The file will open when saved in Developer folder but wont open from anything deeper than that.

Note: I do not encounter this problem in my Documents folder, but I do encounter the problem from DropBox even after moving the User folder into Dropbox and symlinking it back to the native package folder (as suggested by sublime for use with dropbox).

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with spaces being in the folder name messing it up? I'm not familiar with that particular browser.

Comment: Err, I meant to say I'm not familiar with that particular package.

Comment: https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/issues/63